# Variables in graphQL queries

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

EDIT: now with working code below

### The GraphiQL version

I have this query to fetch a [gatsby-image](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-image/):

```
query getImages($fileName: String) {
  landscape: file(relativePath: {eq: $fileName}) {
    childImageSharp {
      fluid(maxWidth: 1000) {
        base64
        tracedSVG
        aspectRatio
        src
        srcSet
        srcWebp
        srcSetWebp
        sizes
        originalImg
        originalName
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And then this query variable:

```
{
  "fileName": "titanic.jpg"
}
```

The above works fine in [GraphiQL](https://github.com/graphql/graphiql).

### The Gatsby version

Now I want to use it in Gatsby, so I have the following code:

```
import React from "react"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"
import Img from "gatsby-image"

export default ({ data }) => (
  <div>
    <Img fluid={data.landscape.childImageSharp.fluid} />
  </div>
)

export const query = (
  graphql`
    query getImages($fileName: String) {
      landscape: file(relativePath: {eq: $fileName}) {
        childImageSharp {
          fluid(maxWidth: 1000) {
            base64
            tracedSVG
            aspectRatio
            src
            srcSet
            srcWebp
            srcSetWebp
            sizes
            originalImg
            originalName
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `,
  {fileName: "knight.jpg"}
)
```

The above doesn't work. `data.landscape.childImageSharp === null`

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

### The working version

Thanks for the help! The following code works pretty well. This [post](https://spectrum.chat/gatsby-js/general/using-variables-in-a-staticquery~abee4d1d-6bc4-4202-afb2-38326d91bd05?m=MTU0NDc1MzE2MjkyNQ==) was particularly helpful. This is not an ideal solution, but it works for me.

```
import React from 'react';
import Img from 'gatsby-image';
import { StaticQuery, graphql } from 'gatsby';

function renderImage(file) {
  return (
    <Img fluid={file.node.childImageSharp.fluid} />
  )
}

const MyImg = function (props) {

  return <StaticQuery
    query={graphql`
      query {
        images: allFile(filter: { sourceInstanceName: { eq: "images" } }) {
          edges {
            node {
              extension
              relativePath
              childImageSharp {
              fluid(maxWidth: 1000) {
                ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    `}
    render={(data) => {
      const image = data.images.edges.find(
        image => image.node.relativePath === "knight.jpg"
      )
      return(renderImage(image))
    }}
  />
}

export default MyImg;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for providing a working version! You saved me hours of work.

Comment: Anyway to pass maxWidth: 1000 or fragment (GatsbyImageSharpFluid) as a variable. That would make it more dynamic.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The two answers (from Bens and Nimish) are wrong in this context, they're not specific to Gatsby.

If you want to use variables in the GraphQL queries, you have to pass them via context in the `createPage` function in `gatsby-node.js` as explained here:
https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/creating-and-modifying-pages/#pass-context-to-pages

You currently can't use variables outside of that, e.g. have a look at this feature request:
https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/discussions/10482

Comment: Sadly, this is the case. I've added some working code based on that second link.

Comment: Your spectrum.chat link doesn't work anymore, is the mentioned discussion available somewhere still?

Answer (score 5):

So to pass variables you have to use the following syntax

```
graphql(`<your_query_with_variable>`, { indexPage: <value_of_variable> })
```

So the query will come something like this

```
    export const query = grapqhl(
     `query getImages($fileName: String) {
      landscape: file(relativePath: {eq: $fileName}) {
        childImageSharp {
          fluid(maxWidth: 1000) {
            base64
            tracedSVG
            aspectRatio
            src
            srcSet
            srcWebp
            srcSetWebp
            sizes
            originalImg
            originalName
           }
         }
       }
     }
    `,
    {fileName: "knight.jpg"}
   )
```

Comment: Note: this will only work in the `gatsby-node` file, passing in a variable to the graphql method with a static query (for example) won't allow variables.