# How can I use a field as a filter from one graphql query to get a fluid image thats in a separate query?

Tags: javascript, graphql, jsx, gatsby

I have two graphql sources, one for fluid images and one for characters in a mongo database. I'm mapping the characters to the page and I need to use the character names (the name field in the "allMongodbMobileLegendsdevChamps") as a filter (using originalName filter possibly) to find the fluid img. So I have something like this

```js
query MyQuery {
  allMongodbMobileLegendsdevChamps {
    nodes {
      name
    }
  }
  allImageSharp(filter: {fluid: {originalName: {eq: "characterName.jpg"}}}) {
    nodes {
      fluid {
        ...allImageSharpFluid
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```js
const Index = ({ data }) => {
  const {
    allMongodbMobileLegendsdevChamps: { nodes: champs },
    allImageSharp: { nodes: fluid },
  } = data
  return (
    <section className={grid}>
      {champs.map(champ => {
        return (
          <Link to={`/champ/${champ.name}`}>
            <Image fluid={fluid.fluid} />
            <h3>{champ.name}</h3>
          </Link>
        )
      })}
    </section>
  )
}
```

If I wasnt using graphql, I'd just set the src in image to "champ.name" like this:

```js
<Image src = `/path/to/img/${champ.name}.jpg` />
```

How can I filter my image query with the champ.name? Should I use Apollo for something like this?

Answer (score 3):

This is Gatsby and currently it is not possible because you can’t pass in variables to queries follow this GH issue https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/10482

Supposing that passing variables was possible, I would make all characters as a page query that will allow me to restructure the name from props and then a static query to which I would pass in the name as filter.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there another way to achieve this without using query variables?

Comment: I am also trying to solve a [similar issue (Show title of next page)](https://github.com/graphql/graphql.github.io/pull/896) but no luck yet

Comment: You can try a janky way. Make your image component as a child component to which you pass in name and interpolate the query string manually and then try passing in that maybe. Not sure if it will work or not.

Comment: is the answer I posted what you meant by interpolating the string?

Comment: Nope I was suggesting similar to this  https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/2293#issue-261880533  (and this doesn’t work) but your way is actually considered better https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/10482#issuecomment-494589454

Answer (score 1):

I used this solution and adapted it slightly for my needs: [Variables in graphQL queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53804219/variables-in-graphql-queries)

In a parent component I map all the champions and create a child component for each one, and pass it the champions name.

In the child component, I have a variable, name, that stores the correct node for the image I want to display by using the find method to match the champions name to the images relativePath (the images have the same exact name as the champion). I then call the function renderImage which consumes the variable "name" and finds the fluid image in node.childImageSharp.fluid, and creates my image component with the correct fluid image location.

```js
import React from "react"
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby"
import { displayName } from "../../utils/championName"
import * as S from "../styled/ChampionGridCard"

const renderImage = file => {
  return <S.ChampionImage fluid={file.node.childImageSharp.fluid} />
}

const ChampionGridCard = props => {
  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    {
      allFile(filter: { sourceInstanceName: { eq: "champImages" } }) {
        edges {
          node {
            extension
            relativePath
            childImageSharp {
              fluid {
                ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  const name = data.allFile.edges.find(
    image => image.node.relativePath === `ssbu/${props.champName}.jpg`
  )

  return (
    <S.ChampionGridCard to={`/champ/${props.champName}`}>
      <S.ChampionImageWrapper>{renderImage(name)}</S.ChampionImageWrapper>
    </S.ChampionGridCard>
  )
}

export default ChampionGridCard
```

Comment: To improve performance you can memoize this similar to this https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/10482#issuecomment-485349612