# How to add variables to graphQL query?

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I am using Gatsby.
I need to increase the limit of 3 to each onCLick.
I've tried to follow [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53804219/variables-in-graphql-queries), but with no success, so I removed the edits, and here is the original code...

This will help me to load more posts.

```
export const LatestNews = ({data}) => {
console.log(data);

  return (
    <section id="news_posts_section">
<p>some data</p>
    </section>
  );
};

export const latestNewsQuery = graphql`
query myquery{
  allMarkdownRemark(
    filter: { frontmatter: { layout: { eq: "news" } } }
    sort: { fields: frontmatter___date, order: DESC }
    limit: 2
  ) {
    nodes {
      frontmatter {
        layout
        title
        path
        date
        featuredImage
        thumbnail
      }
      excerpt(pruneLength: 325)
    }
  }
}
`;
```

Here is my gatsby-node:

```
exports.createPages = ({ actions, graphql }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions;

  const blogPostTemplate = path.resolve('src/templates/blog-post/BlogPost.js');
  const newsTemplate = path.resolve('src/templates/news-single/NewsSingle.js');
  const latestNewsPage = path.resolve(
    'src/components/pages-implementation/news/sections/LatestNews.js',
  );

  const blog = graphql(`
    {
      blog: allMarkdownRemark(
        filter: { frontmatter: { layout: { eq: "blog" } } }
      ) {
        edges {
          node {
            frontmatter {
              path
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `).then((result) => {
    if (result.errors) {
      result.errors.forEach((e) => console.error(e.toString()));
      return Promise.reject(result.errors);
    }
    const posts = result.data.blog.edges;

    posts.forEach((edge) => {
      const { path } = edge.node.frontmatter;
      createPage({
        path: path,
        component: blogPostTemplate,
        context: {},
      });
    });
  });

  const news = graphql(`
    {
      news: allMarkdownRemark(
        filter: { frontmatter: { layout: { eq: "news" } } }
      ) {
        edges {
          node {
            frontmatter {
              path
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `).then((result) => {
    if (result.errors) {
      result.errors.forEach((e) => console.error(e.toString()));
      return Promise.reject(result.errors);
    }
    const news = result.data.news.edges;

    news.forEach((edge) => {
      const { path } = edge.node.frontmatter;
      createPage({
        path: path,
        component: newsTemplate,
        context: {},
      });
    });

    
    news.forEach(edge => {
      createPage({
        path: `/news/`,
        component: latestNewsPage,
        context: {
          // This time the entire product is passed down as context
          product: edge
        }
      });
    });


  });

  return Promise.all([blog, news]);
};
```

**Edit 21 November:**

- I replaced the above code with my attempt to use a non-static query
- I added the gatsby-node config
- I give here a little explanation: the BlogPost.js and NewsSingle.js are templates that create new pages for each post or news post (from Netlify CMS)
- The LatestNews.js is a component in a page. This is the main page of the news. Where are shown all the news? With a static query, it works fine, however, I need to make the "limit" a variable in order to apply a load more button, that onClick will increase the limit, thus showing more news posts on the loop.

With the above configuration it says:

```
warning The GraphQL query in the non-page component "/home/user/projectname/src/components/pages-implementation/news/sections/LatestNews.js" will not be run.
Exported queries are only executed for Page components. It's possible you're
trying to create pages in your gatsby-node.js and that's failing for some
reason.
```

Comment: useStaticQuery - static mean ... static, no variables support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`useStaticQuery` (hence the name) does not allow to receive variables. If you take a look [at the docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/use-static-query/):

> `useStaticQuery` does not accept variables (hence the name “static”),
> but can be used in any component, including pages

The only way to pass variables in a GraphQL query is by using the context API in the `gatsby-node.js`. For example:

```
  queryResults.data.allProducts.nodes.forEach(node => {
    createPage({
      path: `/products/${node.id}`,
      component: productTemplate,
      context: {
        // This time the entire product is passed down as context
        product: node
      }
    });
  });
};
```

In the snippet above, will be a `product` variable in the context with the whole node. It can be accessed through `pageContext` `prop` in the destination template or used as a query parameter.

Comment: Thank you, I tried to apply it. I edited the original post with more information. I hope you can help

Comment: It's not possible to achieve what you are trying to. `gatsby-node.js` (page creation) occurs statically in the build time, so you can add a dynamic variable with a click. You should change the setup to find another workaround. For example, retrieving all posts and showing them 3 by 3 in each click, but without changing the query.

Comment: Thank you, so that makes everything clearer. So maybe a static query as I was doing before, without limit. Memoize all the news and show them more and more onclick?
Do you think this would be a reasonable solution?

Comment: It depends on your needs. If you are creating dynamic pages for each post I would highly recommend using the `gatsby-node.js` approach. If not, (using a SPA to only show all posts) I would recommend a page query. The static query is expensive in terms of performance if retrieves a lot of data and it should be used for static parameters that you want to reuse in some shared components (header/footer links, metadata, etc).

Comment: I was able to make it work. Instead of loading it in the component, I made the same query in the "page component". Sent the `data` in the props of the component that loads the news. Changed it into an array and memoized. Then onClick I change the array to display thanks to `splice` and hooks. It works great!