# React Gatsby Graph QL - filter articles for sitemap

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby, gatsby-plugin

I have created a Gatsby blog using Flexiblocks. The issue is i want to create a sitemap specifically for `Google News` which will be different from main sitemap of the blog. For this sitemap i need to filter articles which were published within last two days.
I am using this [plugin](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-advanced-sitemap/)

```
 allArticle(sort: {order: DESC, fields: date}, filter: {date: {WHAT_SHOULD_I_DO_HERE}}) {
    edges {
      node {
        date
        excerpt
        title
        link
        slug
      }
    }
  }
```

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

**UPDATE**

`{date: {gte: "2021-08-27T13:11:30.443Z"}}` will filter the articles, but how can i get this date string dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

Gatsby relies on [`momentjs`](https://momentjs.com/) under the hood when dealing with dates in GraphQL scope. You just need to add the variable returned from a function in the scope of the query like:

```
const getTwoDaysAgo=()=> moment().subtract(2, "days");
```

In your `gatsby-config.js` you just can call this function and:

To add a variable you can follow thee answers in: [Variables in graphQL queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53804219/variables-in-graphql-queries)

Basically, following this syntax:

```
grapqhl(
     `query getImages($fileName: String) {
      landscape: file(relativePath: {eq: $fileName}) {
        childImageSharp {
          fluid(maxWidth: 1000) {
            base64
            tracedSVG
            aspectRatio
            src
            srcSet
            srcWebp
            srcSetWebp
            sizes
            originalImg
            originalName
           }
         }
       }
     }
    `,
    {fileName: "knight.jpg"}
   )
```

You can add custom variables. In this case, note that the query is wrapped inside `graphql()` function. Applied to your case, you can try:

```
plugins: [
    {
        resolve: `gatsby-plugin-advanced-sitemap`,
        options: {
          query: graphql(
             ` 
              query allArticle(
               sort: {
                 order: DESC, fields: date
               }, 
              filter: {date: {twoDaysAgo}}) {
              edges {
                node {
                  date
                  excerpt
                  title
                  link
                  slug
                }
              }
            }`, {twoDaysAgo: getTwoDaysAgo()}
          )
      }
    }
 ]
```

*Note: be careful copy/pasting because there's a lot of brackets that I may miss.*

I'm not sure if the plugin will support that notation but it should.

---

> {date: {gte: "2021-08-27T13:11:30.443Z"}}

Given the edited question, adapt the flow and the filter to the `gte` parameter.

Comment: Thanks, i'll try this and let you know

Comment: I am unable to use this in gastby-config.js :(